# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in /home1/j8f5w8o7/nepe.smeext-carding.com/pieces/inc.php on line 26

Tags: mysqli

Tengo 2 problemas que aparecen al inicio de mi sitio, y son los siguientes:

> ```
> Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in
> /home1/j8f5w8o7/nepe.smeext-carding.com/pieces/inc.php on line 26
>
> Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null given in 
> /home1/j8f5w8o7/nepe.smeext-carding.com/pieces/inc.php on line 27
> ```

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
session_start();
ob_start();

$display = new display();
$user = new user();

DEFINE("localhost", "");
DEFINE("j8f5w8o7_finix", "");
DEFINE("yael2204", "");
DEFINE("j8f5w8o7_finix", "");

$sql = new mysqli(host, username, password, database);

function __destruct()
{
    ob_clean();
}

class settings
{
    public static function website($data)
    {
        global $sql;

        $website = mysqli_query($sql, 'SELECT * FROM merchant LIMIT 1');
        $fwebsite = mysqli_fetch_array($website);

        return $fwebsite[$data];
    }
}

class display {
    public static function success($msg)
    {
        echo('<div class="alert alert-success role="alert" style="text-align: center;">'.$msg.'</div>');
    }
    public static function error($msg)
    {
        echo('<div class="alert alert-danger role="alert" style="text-align: center;">'.$msg.'</div>');
    }
}

class user {
    function IsLogged()
    {
        global $sql;

        /* If session exists. */

        if(!isset($_SESSION['auth'])){
            header('Location: signin.php');
            exit();
        }

        /* Additional check.If session is null or user does not exists. */

        if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {
            if(is_numeric($_SESSION['auth']) && !empty($_SESSION['auth'])) {
                $query = mysqli_query($sql, 'SELECT UserName FROM users WHERE UserID = "'.$_SESSION['auth'].'"');

                if(mysqli_num_rows($query) == 0) {
                    unset($_SESSION['auth']);
                    header('Location: signin.php');
                    exit();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function IsBanned()
    {
        $banned = $this->GetData('UserBanned');

        if($banned == 1) {
            header('Location: ./index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

    function IsAdmin()
    {
        if($this->GetData('UserAdmin') == 0) {
            header('Location: ./index.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

    function HasMembership()
    {
        if($this->GetData('UserMembership') == 0) {
            header('Location: ./purchase.php');
            exit();
        }
    }

    function GetData($data)
    {
        global $sql;

        if(isset($_SESSION['auth'])) {
            $id = $_SESSION['auth'];

            if(is_numeric($id)) {
                $query = mysqli_query($sql, 'SELECT '.$data.' FROM users WHERE UserID = "'.$id.'"');
                $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
                return $row[$data];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Al crear la conexion a la BBDD no estas indicandole los valores necesarios.

Comment: Disculpa, pero como lo hago?

Comment: mysqli debe recibir por orden los siguientes campos acerca de tu bbdd: host, username, password, database. por ejemplo mysqli ("localhost", "miusuario", "mipassword", "mibasededatos");

Comment: Tus DEFINE son incorrectos. Revisa el Manual: http://php.net/manual/es/function.define.php Debería ser `DEFINE ("NOMBRE_CONSTANTE", "VALOR_CONSTANTE");` por eso la conexión no reconoce las credenciales  (usuario, password, etc) que crees estarle pasando.

Answer (score 1):

Evidentemente estás intentando definir constantes con las credenciales para conectar a la base de datos.

Se puede hacer, pero no tiene mucho sentido, ya que en PHP las constantes son una especie de variables globales.

> Igual que las [superglobales](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.predefined.php), el acceso a una constante es global. Se
>   puede acceder a constantes desde cualquier sitio del script sin
>   importar desde donde. Para más información en el acceso, lea el manual
>   en la sección [acceso a variables](http://php.net/manual/es/language.variables.scope.php).
>
> <sub>❯ Fuente: [Constantes en el Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/language.constants.php)</sub>

Así que, aplicando buenas prácticas de programación, una constante sería definida para usarla en varias partes del código... aquí **lo que interesaría usar en varias partes del código es la conexión en sí misma** (por ejemplo mediante una clase de conexión), por lo que definir constantes sobra en este caso.

Si de todos modos quieres usar constantes, la forma correcta sería:

```
DEFINE("HOST", "localhost");
DEFINE("USERNAME", "j8f5w8o7_finix");
DEFINE("PASSWORD", "yael2204");
DEFINE("DATABASE", "j8f5w8o7_finix");

$mysqli = new mysqli(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
```

Verás que las he puesto en mayúscula, porque así lo exige la convención de nombres (ver enlace anterior del Manual).

Para la conexión a la base de datos lo recomendable es tener una clase dedicada a la conexión que te devuelva un objeto conexión, cada vez que lo necesites. Para conectar a la bd puedes definir variables simples ya que no necesitas que dichas variables tengan un alcance global, además ocuparán menos memoria que una constante.

Ejemplo:

```
$host="localhost";
$username="j8f5w8o7_finix";
$password="yael2204";
$database="j8f5w8o7_finix";
$mysqli = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $database);
```

Teniendo una clase que devuelva el objeto de conexión `$mysqli` la misma usaría en local las credenciales y te devolvería la **conexión** que es lo que te interesa. Mientras menos públicas y menos globales sean tus credenciales, mejor. Así que usar `DEFINE` para credenciales de conexión podría ser considerado una mala práctica.

También he llamado a la conexión `$mysqli`porque generalmente el objeto conexión se llama así, o $con, o $bd ... es una cuestión de gustos y ... de aplicar reglas de convención de nombres, ya que `$sql` se suele usar para consultas tales como `SELECT ... FROM ...`, `INSERT INTO ...`, etc.